# Layout in rails

Tags: ruby, layout

now i want to using Layout to make inner layout for my backEnd

my concept it to make all the pages under the controller called backend  to be like

http://www.local.com/backend/index   (for login page)

http://www.local.com/backend/Add     (for add new user)

http://www.local.com/backend/Pass    (for change password)

http://www.local.com/backend/Upload  (for upload images)

so all the pages must be a method under the controller `backEnd`

it mean my **backend** layout will be for all the pages if i use it like that

```
class BackendController < ApplicationController
 layout 'standard'  ######### my layout ########
  def index

  end

  def Add

  end

  def Upload

  end

  def Pass

  end

end
```

my question is

**how i can make my layout loaded to some pages like (Add,Pass,Upload) and make another layout 
for the index without can appear it to the another pages in the same controller ??**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this, for example:

```
class BackendController < ApplicationController
  layout 'standard', except: :index
  layout 'for_index', only: :index
```

Comment: Thanks Sergio , it work well with me , I'm accepted the answer    *_^